# Redirecting all subdomains to https via .htaccess file

Tags: .htaccess, ssl, redirect, https, http-redirect

In anticipation of the Google Chrome change going live on July 1, I want to make sure all the files on a site I manage redirect to https.  It's an Apache server and I have the following already in the file (using a fake domain name for demo purposes):

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/[0-9]+\..+\.cpaneldcv$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/\.well-known/pki-validation/[A-F0-9]{32}\.txt(?:\ Comodo\ DCV)?$
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} 80 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://example.com/$1 [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example.com [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/[0-9]+\..+\.cpaneldcv$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/\.well-known/pki-validation/[A-F0-9]{32}\.txt(?:\ Comodo\ DCV)?$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.example.com/$1 [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example.org$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.example.org$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/[0-9]+\..+\.cpaneldcv$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/\.well-known/pki-validation/[A-F0-9]{32}\.txt(?:\ Comodo\ DCV)?$
RewriteRule ^/?$ "https\:\/\/www\.example\.com\/" [R=301,L]
```

As you can see above, there is a redirect from a domain I'm parking (example.org) to the main domain I'm managing (example.com).  Other than that, all I want to have happen is for all pages of the site, including all subdomains to redirect to the https version of each page.  For example, when someone goes to http://webmail.example.com I would like them to go to https://webmail.example.com or when an admin goes to http://cpanel.example.com, they should be redirected to https://cpanel.example.com

I like keeping www in the URL for links not in a subdomain on this site.  For example, if someone goes to http://example.com/folder/file I want them to go to https://www.example.com/folder/file

The above code is located in the .htaccess file of the root folder.  Do I need to have a .htaccess file in a folder for each subdomain in order to get this to work?  Or am I just doing something wrong in the existing .htaccess file?

Comment: For "fake domain", use `example.com`, `example.net`, `example.org` and `.example` TLD in configuration, not something else. See RFC2606 for all details.

Comment: If you have full control of the server, it is better for all kind of reasons (simplicity, security, performances) to just edit the main configuration files (or files included from them) instead of using `.htaccess`. Especially for URL rewriting this makes thing far easier. You do not describe properly the errors you get for now. Also you are a little offtopic here since it is not a programming question. See [sf] maybe instead, or [Webmasters.se] (read their Tour).

Comment: Thanks for your comments.  I edited to include the proper fake domain names.

Regarding the errors, I narrowed it down more.  I'm able to get subdomains to load https except for ones like cpanel and webmail.  I contacted my hosting company about this and they advised for system-generated subdomains like that to use the URL that includes the proper port (for example, port 2096 for webmail).  I then asked, well, what if I have users that don't know the port number and they didn't have an answer.  Perhaps a URL redirect of the URL without the port number to the one including a port number?

Comment: BTW in latest case, you should not have to escape each slash in the final URL you redirect too.

Comment: I believe cPanel did that for me when I added the redirect.  Thanks for the note.  I'll update it.